# How to format datetime from string

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have one string like this "2012 12 12 12:12", how to format as a Date ?

I try this but not work

```
-(NSDate *)stringToDate:(NSString *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

    [formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [formatter setDateFormat : @"yyyy MM dd HH:mm"];

    NSString *stringTime = date;

    NSDate *dateTime = [formatter dateFromString:stringTime];
    [formatter release];
    return dateTime;
}
```

Update: when I change the position of formatter, it also can not work by:

```
NSLog(@"%@", stringToDate(@"2012 12 12 12:12"));
```

It outputs "null", But it works with string format like "2012-12-12 12:12"

Comment: You really need a refresher on Objective-C memory management...

Comment: When I change the position of formatter , it also can not work

Comment: But at least it no more invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Check my answer. I have updated it with the NSLog.

Comment: With the update, I'm surprised this code even compiles. You're using `stringToDate` as a function, whereas it's defined as an Objective-C method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this,

```
[formatter setDateFormat : @"yyyy MM dd HH:mm"];
[formatter release];
NSString *stringTime = date;
NSDate *dateTime = [formatter dateFromString:stringTime];
```

to

```
[formatter setDateFormat : @"yyyy MM dd HH:mm"];
NSString *stringTime = date;
NSDate *dateTime = [formatter dateFromString:stringTime];
[formatter release];
```

Don't release formatter until you are done with the use of it in converting from string to date. In your code, you are releasing it before the conversion itself.

**Update:**

You need to use it as,

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self stringToDate:@"2012 12 12 12:12"]);
```

You can not use `stringToDate(@"2012 12 12 12:12")` in objective-c. Equivalent here is `[self stringToDate:@"2012 12 12 12:12"]`.

Comment: @why, In that case, it should work fine if `[[guideElement attributeForName:@"start"] stringValue]` is returning "2012 12 12 12:12".

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
```

instead of these two lines:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
...
[formatter release];
```

If you use ARC, then no trouble to you for memory management.

EDIT: But kindly read some memory management rules and guidelines, that is a must for everyone working in cococa.

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing `NSDateFormatter` before it is used

Use this code :-

```
-(NSDate *)stringToDate:(NSString *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

    [formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [formatter setDateFormat : @"yyyy MM dd HH:mm"];

    NSString *stringTime = date;

    NSDate *dateTime = [formatter dateFromString:stringTime];
    [formatter release];

    return dateTime;
}
```